# Visiting website from command-line shows Plesk default page

Tags: centos

I have a server running CentOS 6.5 and Plesk 11 where I have added a couple of websites.

If I open a website from my computer, it will display okay, but if I open it from the server itself, it will show "Plesk default page".

Looks like the vhosts are not resolving correctly if I'm visiting the page from the server's command line:

```
[root@webscoming conf]# lynx http://www.example.com/

Parallels Plesk Parallels

Web Server's Default Page

   This page is generated by Parallels Plesk, the leading hosting automation software. You see this page because there is no Web site
   at this address.
```

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 3):

`lynx` doesn't support Host headers, so your vhosts won't work (as they rely on this header).

Normal browsers do send the header, so that's why it works there.

Comment: Hmm, but this is quite strange, I mean, I have other servers where I can run "lynx <name of website on the same server>" and it does open. What I basically needed is to be able to do a file_get_contents on a absolute url from a website on the same server, and gives me a 404 because of showing the Plesk default page instead of the real page.

Comment: That's easy to manipulate. I'm assuming PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779540/add-headers-to-file-get-contents-in-php

Comment: The other servers probably worked because you only have one domain...

Comment: Nathan on other server I haven't got only one domain, I also have multiple domains, I personally think it is a issue that has to do with how the server is configured, maybe apache or something because connecting from outside it locates the correct website but connecting from localhost it locates the default plesk page. Could it be the "NameVirtualHost *:80" line on apache extra vhost conf? that's what I have on my computer with XAMPP, but on the server I've found this: http://pastebin.com/zhPznqw9

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

I don't know why it happened, but the support guys fixed it by adding a line in the HOSTS file for that domain pointing to the LAN ip of the server.

Something like:

```
172.26.0.217 www.example.com
```